# Blazor webassembly css is loaded but fonts not, Using HeadContent and HeadOutlet

Tags: css, fonts, blazor-webassembly

I have this in my layout:

```
@{
    string lang = loc["lang"];
    string siteStyleSheetName = $"site-{lang}.css";
}
<HeadContent>
    <link href=@($"css/{siteStyleSheetName}") rel="stylesheet" />
</HeadContent>
```

Also my stylesheet looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Imperial';
    src: url('fonts/en/imperial-normal-400.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/en/imperial-normal-700.woff') format('woff');
}


@media (max-width: 1600px) {


    html, body {
        font-family: Imperial, Tahoma, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
   
}
```

the fonts folder is in the same folder as my css file, I can verify that site-en.css is loaded in browser sources, but the css loads and font not, This exact setup works in blazor server but not in webassembly.
Help.